# remove field name from power bi chart

Tags: powerbi

The chart in the image has field names coming  closed jobs and open jobs on both horizontal and speciality name on and vertical axis. I need to remove these. I am using 100% stacked bar chart. I have tried to find category in "Visualizations" but there was nothing there to remove this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

All of these can be disabled in the Format section of the Visualization pane.

[image: Format]

The X axis and Y axis have a Title toggle you can set when you expand them.